# Есть ли ещё кроме tkinter библиотеки для создания оконных отображений?

Tags: python

Хотел бы узнать есть ли библиотеки для оконных приложений для windows?

Comment: Qt, wxWidget, Kivi, GTK. Выбирайте.

Comment: @Lecron, а есть библиотеки, чтобы можно было просто элементы накидать?

Comment: Что значит "элементы накидать"? Вам нужен визуальный конструктор формы? Если да, то это вопрос не к библиотекам, а к среде разработки.

Comment: Да. Мне нужно визуальный конструктор. Извините не правильно выразился

Comment: Возьмите PyQt5 и визуальный редактор Qt Designer.